# How to Fix linter-Flake8 in atom for Python Configuration

Tags: python-3.x, atom-editor, flake8

#### Introduction

After I installed `atom` into my `debian-ParrotOS` for coding `python`. I've tried to search for `flake8` for helping me to figure out the problems while writing code.

#### The Problem

after I installed `linter-flake8` using this command: `pip install flake8`

It showed me that this line:

```
[Linter] Error running Flake8
See console for more info
```

#### What I've done

I tried several times to re-install `linter-flake8`. Even I tried to search multiple times for another alterative but all of them was not effcient as `linter-flake8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Fix Linter flake8

### Description:

- This's the solution for fixing the console problem which we're facing when we decide to install ***Linter-flake8*** for ***Python3***. It has been tested in ***Linux*** and ***Debian***.

### Why ***Linter-flake8*** doesn't work after installation?

- ***Linter-flake8*** default installation meant to be for `python 2.7` beside if you read the description of the package, you will also find that their implementation was for `python 2.7` not for `python3`.
- Default installation package simulates directly with `python 2.7`, not for `python3`. so, you have to install the package using the commands of `python3`.
- Even after inserting your **Executable PATH** will be only mere of spectacular. Because you need to install flake8 in terms of `python3`, not `python2`.

### So, What should I do?

1. Install ***Linter-flake8*** From **Atom** and then restart your IDE.
2. Check if it's actually being installed via your package manager by executing: `which flake8` in your terminal.
3. Reopen your IDE and click `Ctrl+Shift+P` to open the Search in **Atom**.
4. Search for *Application: Open the Init Script*.
5. Then, Write in the *init.coffee* this code:

   ```coffee
   process.env.PATH = ['usr/local/bin/', process.env.PATH].join(':')
   ```
6. Go To your ***Executable PATH** and paste this path `/usr/local/bin/`.
7. Then, open a new Terminal and execute these commands:

   1. First, enter your **root Mode** by `sudo su`.
   2. Second, go to `cd /usr/local/bin/`.
   3. Third, execute these commands:

      - `python3 -m pip install flake8`.
      - `ls`
      - `apm install linter-flake8`
      - `ls`
      - `python3 -m pip install flake8-docstring`
      - `python3 -m pip install hacking`

If you didn't install *pip* before, then you can install it by `sudo apt-get install pip` and then, you can move on to continue the installation of flake8.

8. close your **Atom** and open it.
9. If you want to disable The ***Max Line Lenght*** you can do that by `Default: 0`.
10. ***Smile!***

It will be a courtesy from you if you start following me :) <3

## References:

- [flake8 not found](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-flake8/issues/18)
- [linter-flake8](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-flake8)